# Why is headless NetLogo simulation running slower on a high end computer cluster than on my desktop?

Tags: java, performance, netlogo, headless

On my university’s high end computing cluster, I use the following script to run a Java program (repls.class):

```
#$ -S /bin/bash
#$ -q serial
#$ -l h_vmem=10G
source /etc/profile
module add java
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:`pwd`
java -Xmx3000M -Xms128M -Djava.awt.headless=true -classpath ".:./netlogo/app/netlogo-6.1.0.jar" repls 1 1 1 5 "E,16070608MAT,16070608MAT,L160706-08-MATHS-R3.txt,L160706-08-MATHS.csv"
```

(The cluster operating system is CentOS Linux, with job submission handled by Son of Grid Engine.)

‘repls.class’ starts NetLogo, running my program ‘VizSim19Calib.nlogo’ headlessly.  It also sets several global variables for the run.
‘VizSim19Calib.nlogo’ runs many simulations (replications – but testing with 5).

**The problem is that each simulation is taking approx. 3 s to run, whereas on my own desktop each simulation takes approx. 1.5 s!**

It doesn’t matter what settings I use for virtual memory, heap or stack – even doubling these makes no difference, viz.:  #$ -l h_vmem=20G and -Xmx6000M -Xms256M

**Why does the simulation run so slowly? 
Could the location of the NetLogo class and jar files be responsible?**
They are in directories under my home folder.

My Java program ‘repls.java’ is basically:

```
import org.nlogo.headless.HeadlessWorkspace;
public class repls {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {   …
        HeadlessWorkspace workspace =
            HeadlessWorkspace.newInstance() ;
        try {
            workspace.open("VizSim19Calib.nlogo",false);
            workspace.command("startup");
            workspace.command("set Test? false");   
            workspace.command("set SIMULATION-RUN-ID " + args[0]);      
            …
            workspace.command(
              "RunOneLessonParamReps SelectedLessonData #Replications"
                        );
            workspace.dispose();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            …
        }
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) { 
        …
    } } }
```

Comment: First guess would be Java version differences between the systems.  Are you getting your 1.5s number locally using the same/similar script you're using on the cluster?  Is your desktop running a different OS than the cluster?  With those numbers being so small, it could be almost anything - from disk latency to thread spin-up times of the OS.  Since you're already running a custom app to execute the model, you could add some profiling statements to see where the differences in time are (or if they're outside the app entirely).

Comment: Thanks.  Good ideas.  Yes, it's not really a fair comparison: average desktop W10 with newer version of Java vs Linux on cluster.  Same repls.java program but of necessity different batch scripts for Windows and Linux server.  But I did expect the cluster to be faster no matter what.  I have millions of replications to run so even 0.1s is important.  As you suggest I'll investigate where I can make improvements.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I realized that NetLogo was using all 4 cores on my desktop, but only 1 on one of the university cluster's single compute nodes, by default. I increased this to 4 then 8 cores, and the speed improvement is as desired! I'll try 16 tonight. I think the matter is closed.